# How to get column value from next record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following result set:

```
POST                   |    DATE
--------------------------------------
Senior Software Engg.  |    2018-04-18
Software Engg.         |    2017-04-18
Assoc. Software Engg.  |    2016-04-18
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT designation_id as id, d.title as POST, DATE(dt_datetime) as DATE
    FROM users_history_check u
    INNER JOIN
    designations d 
    ON d.id = u.designation_id
    WHERE u.id = $userID
    ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

I want to fetch next record and perform date difference calculation in months, and display records.

Expected Output :

```
POST                   |    Start DATE  |  End DATE   |  MONTHS
---------------------------------------------------------------
Senior Software Engg.  |    2018-04-18  |   -         |
Software Engg.         |    2017-04-18  |  2018-04-18 |  12
Assoc. Software Engg.  |    2016-04-18  |  2017-04-18 |  12
```

Something like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT designation_id as id, d.title as POST, DATE(dt_datetime) as Start DATE, NEXT_RECORD(DATE(dt_datetime)) as End DATE, DATEDIFF(Start DATE, End DATE) as MONTHS....
```

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT `POST`, 
        `DATE`,
        IFNULL(END_DATE,'') AS END_DATE,
        IFNULL(MONTH,'') AS MONTH
FROM
(SELECT `POST`, 
        `DATE`,
        @prev AS END_DATE,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(month,DATE,@prev) AS MONTH,
        @prev := T.DATE AS VarDate
FROM Table1 T,
(SELECT @prev:=null)R
) T1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
POST                    DATE        END_DATE    MONTH
Senior Software Engg.   2018-04-18      
Software Engg.          2017-04-18  2018-04-18  12
Assoc. Software Engg.   2016-04-18  2017-04-18  12
```

**Demo Link**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33260/15

**EXPLANATION:**

In Sub query, I am saving the `Date` value in `@prev` variable and in each row using that variable to calculate the `END_DATE` before assigning the current date value from Column `Date`.
Then using the sub query to present the data in a proper way.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the previous date using variables:

```
SELECT id, post, date,
       (CASE WHEN (@tmp_prevd := @prevd) = NULL THEN NULL  -- never happens
             WHEN (@prevd := date) = NULL THEN NULL  -- never happens
             ELSE @tmp_prevd
        END) as prev_date
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT designation_id as id, d.title as POST, DATE(dt_datetime) as DATE
      FROM users_history_check u INNER JOIN
           designations d 
           ON d.id = u.designation_id
      WHERE u.id = $userID
      ORDER BY DATE DESC
     ) ud CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @prevd := NULL) params;
```

This is tricky, because all references to a variable need to be in the same expression.  That is why this uses `CASE` in a rather arcane way.

In MySQL 8.0 and basically all other databases, you could use `LEAD()` instead.

Comment: I'm getting `[BLOB - 10 B]` value in prev-date field. What does that mean?

Comment: @Azima . . . I have no idea.  Is that a value in your data?

Answer (score 2):

Try This....

```
 SELECT T1.POST,T1.DATE  ,T2.DATE,DATEDIFF(MONTH,T1.DATE,T2.DATE)
 FROM(

   SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS SlNo,*
   FROM Mytable)T1
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY DATE DESC)+1 AS SlNo,*
   FROM Mytable)T2
   ON(T1.SlNo = T2.SlNo  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using self-join like this

```
select d1.post, 
       d1.d `start DATE`, 
       min(d2.d) `end DATE`, 
       timestampdiff(month, d1.d, min(d2.d)) `MONTHS`
from data d1
left join data d2 on d1.d < d2.d
group by d1.post, d1.d
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=047e4d865279a837f57455760332db96)

The data table is the result of your SQL. It can be added using `WITH` or you may use subquery as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * ,Datediff(Month,[Date],endate) 
FROM
(
SELECT *,Lead( [Date], 1, Null) OVER (
     ORDER BY [Date]) AS Endate --INTO SourceTable 
FROM
(                  
SELECT 'Senior Software Engg.' POST    ,   '2018-04-18' DATE UNION ALL
SELECT 'Software Engg.'        POST    ,   '2017-04-18' DATE UNION ALL
SELECT 'Assoc. Software Engg.'  POST   ,    '2016-04-18' DATE 
)A
)B
ORDER BY [Date] desc
```